# Expanding Prolog clauses with forall/2

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming, swi-prolog

I'm using [`clause/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=clause/2) to transform some Prolog clauses in a compiler. I need to replace the head of each clause with its body, but `clause/2` sometimes doesn't expand the clause in the way that it was originally written.

Here, `clause/2` expands `demo(A,B)` to `\+ (call(A),\+call(B))`, instead of expanding its original definition:

```
:- use_module(prolog_to_minizinc).
:- initialization(main).

main :- 
        writeln(forall(A,B)),
        clause(demo(A,B),Clause),
        writeln(Clause).

demo(A,B) :-
    forall(A,B).
```

Is there another way to expand clauses, without modifying clauses that include `forall/2`?

Comment: Note that the `forall/2` predicate can and is usually defined as `forall(A,B) :- \+ (call(A), \+ call(B))`...

Comment: But here, I expected `demo(A,B)` to be expanded to `forall(A,B)`.

Comment: Without you posting the term-expanding code that you're using, is difficult to advise.

Comment: @PauloMoura It's part of a [Prolog-to-MiniZinc](https://github.com/jarble/prolog-to-minizinc) compiler. This compiler expands clauses using `clause/2,` but I need to expand each clause without modifying the definition. I expected `clause(demo(A,B),Clause)` to unify `Clause` with `forall(A,B)`, but it didn't work as I intended.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: at least on SWI the `listing(demo/2)` already shows the expanded code after consulting that procedure, so i believe some compile optimization makes the original construct to be lost when consulting it.

Comment: Not loading prolog_to_minizinc module in SWI-Prolog 8.1.19 gives `forall(_7212,_7214) forall(_7212,_7214) true.` `listing(demo)` also shows unexpanded code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unwanted expansion of the `forall/2` goal is due to SWI-Prolog loading `library(apply_macros)` at startup. This library provides the expansion code for `forall/2` and other predicates. Finding how `library(apply_macros)` is loaded is not trivial as setting the `verbose_autoload` flag to `true` in the `~/.config/swi-prolog/init.pl` file doesn't print all libraries that are being auto-loaded at startup. On my laptop, using the current devel git version of SWI-Prolog (`8.1.21-82-ge6e1d5376-DIRTY`):

```
?- current_module(apply_macros).
true.

?- module_property(apply_macros, P).
P = class(library) ;
P = file('/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl/library/apply_macros.pl') ;
P = line_count(36) ;
P = exports([expand_phrase/2, expand_phrase/4]) .

?- source_file_property('/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl/library/apply_macros.pl', P).
P = modified(1547476368.0) ;
P = source(file) ;
P = module(apply_macros) ;
P = load_context(nb_set, '/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl/library/nb_set.pl':45, [imports([])]) ;
P = load_count(1) ;
P = number_of_clauses(52).

?- source_file_property('/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl/library/nb_set.pl', P).
P = modified(1547476368.0) ;
P = source(file) ;
P = module(nb_set) ;
P = load_context(solution_sequences, '/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl/library/solution_sequences.pl':46, []) ;
P = load_count(1) ;
P = number_of_clauses(13).

?- source_file_property('/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl/library/solution_sequences.pl', P).
P = modified(1574086719.0) ;
P = source(file) ;
P = module(solution_sequences) ;
P = load_context(editline, '/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl/library/editline.pl':59, []) ;
P = load_count(1) ;
P = number_of_clauses(49).
```

The file `editline.pl` provides the **default** convenient command-line history and other services. But if you switch to `readline` by adding to your `~/.config/swi-prolog/init.pl` file the directive:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(readline, readline).
```

Then you get:

```
?- [user].
|: a(A,B) :- forall(A,B).
|: % user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- listing(a/2).
% autoloading user:listing/1 from /Users/pmoura/lib/swipl/library/listing
a(A, B) :-
    forall(A, B).

true.
```

This is a poor workaround but it may help you.